# Bounding the size of a set that is a little better than a dominating set

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

So I am doing this problem.

Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ vertices, and let $\delta>10$ be the minimum degree. I want to show that there exists a partition of the vertices $A$ and $B$ such that for each $b\in B$, there is a neighbor in $A$ and a neighbor in $B$, with the property that $|A|\leq \Omega(n\ln (\delta)/\delta)$

This was my approach:

Create a random set $X$ defined by $v\in X$ with probability $p$ (to be chosen later) and $v\notin X$ with probability $1-p$. Then define the (random) set $Y$ to be $\{v\in V: v\notin X$ and it does not have any neighborhs in $X\}$. Lastly, define a (random) set $Z$ be $\{v\in V: v\notin X,v\notin Y, $ and $v$ does not have any neighborhs in $(X\cup Y)^c\}$

Then consider the set $X\cup Y\cup Z$. I will let this be my set $A$ and the complement will be $B$. By construction it will have the properties I desire.

Then,

$E[X]=np$ is clear.
 $E[Y]=n\cdot P(v\in Y)=n\cdot (1-p)\cdot (1-p)^{deg(v)}=n(1-p)^{deg(v)+1}\leq n(1-p)^{\delta+1}\leq ne^{-p(\delta+1)}$
$E[Z]=n\cdot P(v\in Z)=n(1-p)(1-(1-p)^{deg(v)+1})(p+(1-p)^{deg(v)+1})^{deg(v)}\leq n(1-p)(p+(1-p)^{\delta+1})^\delta\leq ne^{-p}\cdot (p+e^{-p(\delta+1)})$

Here I am sort of happy with the bound for $E[|X|]$ and $E[|Y|]$, but I feel I was too lose with the bound obtained for $E[|Z|]$

Then, $E[|A|]=E[|X|+|Y|+|Z|]\leq n(p+e^{-p(\delta+1)}+e^{-p}(p+e^{-p(\delta+1)}))=n(e^{-p}+1)(p+e^{-p(\delta+1)})$

Let $p=\ln(\delta+1)/(\delta+1)$ to obtain:

$E[|A|]\leq n((\frac{1}{\delta+1})^{1/(\delta+1)}+1)(\frac{\ln(\delta+1)}{\delta+1}+\frac{1}{\delta+1})<4n\ln(\delta+1)/(\delta+1)<5n\ln(\delta)/\delta$

So even though the problem is solved, I was wondering if one could do somewhat better. I think there is a lot lost on my bound of $E[|Z|]$, so I was wondering if one could do better than $\Omega(n\ln(\delta)/\delta)$

Comment: The reason why Im happy with $E[|X|]$ and $E[|Y|]$ is because I only use the bound $1-p\leq e^{-p}$ which is a rather good one for small positive $p$, and since I let $p=\ln(\delta+1)/(\delta+1)$ this will be small.

Comment: Is there a power $\delta$ missing at the end of $E[|Z|]$ expression? Looks like it should be $ne^{-p}(p+e^{-p(\delta + 1)})^{\delta}$.